# Can I use subsections in place of lists

Tags: academic-writing

Is it ok to use subsections in place of lists? Consider the following:

%----------------------------------------------------

1. My plans %(section starts here)

abcdefgh ijkl..... Following are my specific plans:

1.1 Plan1

................................

1.2 Plan 2..............

%-----------------------------------------------------------

I need to keep the section / subsection format. However, I feel that with the colon introduced before, the subsections are serving more as a list, rather typical subsections. Should I do away with the colon and write a full sentence like " I will describe my specific plans in the following paragraphs" ?
Hope this is the right community to ask this sort of question.
Thanks,

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you are asking. What do you mean, for example, by 'with the colon introduced before'?

Comment: What I meant was that, is it ok to write "Following are my specific plans:" before the subsection starts?  Generally we do this in case of lists. Hope I have been able to explain.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, the answer is yes. If you have a list a colon is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> ## 1. My plans %(section starts here)
>
> abcdefgh ijkl..... In the sections below I'll go into my specific plans.
>
> ### 1.1. Plan1
>
> ................................
>
> ### 1.2. Plan 2..............

I.e. remove the colon.

It's not at all strange to assume one part of the text points to later parts. I think it's more of an implicit expectation from a reader of both fiction and non-fiction that the earlier parts and the later parts are tied together somehow.

Other alternatives:

> ## 1. My plans
>
> Plans are good for you. You should have at least one at any given moment. When I was a kid I wanted to go to the moon, now I've evolved my plans some.
>
> ### 1.1. Go to business school
>
> Going to business school will be .....

Or:

> ## 1. My plans
>
> ### 1.1. Go to business school
>
> Going to business school will be .....

As long as there's text after the header, you should probably use sections rather than lists. But if it's just a list of your plans, a paragraph each, then a list might be more appropriate.

> My plans:
>
> 1. I want to go to business school to feel the pulse of the economy.
> 2. I want to learn to tango to feel the pulse of life!
> 3. .....

If you want a list with a header, I suggest an introduction about plans somehow. Maybe through an anecdote, or your general thoughts about plans, or even an expansion on your most important plan.

> ## 1. My plans
>
> My most important plan will always be to live a meaningful life. Every other plan I make is an attempt to fulfill this plan.
>
> 1. I want to go to business school to feel the pulse of the economy.
> 2. I want to learn to tango to feel the pulse of life!
> 3. .....